# How to include jquery to joomla2.5 article

Tags: jquery, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7, joomla3.0

I am using joomla2.5,I need to have a jquery effect on one of my page(not the home page) so I am wondering can I include jquery to joomla article if not then what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the jquery in index.php in the `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use addscript function in template to load jquery in the head section.

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js');
?>
```

But be aware that you have to use [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function, because joomla sometimes uses mootools framework.

Comment: I need to include jquery in a article only because I don't want to display it on index.php can I do?

Comment: Sure you just need to install [jumi](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/1023) to allow php in article then just use the script in my answer